# Application breaks while View Redirect to Azure login

Tags: azure, powerbi, asp.net-mvc-5.2, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have a mvc application , Which have a Home view , in the Home View I have  Button  to see the report , Which is loading two partial view one is get the ajax call and load the  external api data from table ,another one  partial view is for load powerbi.

while click the button, i have load different api and get the datas in 1 partial view and while loading the second partial view for PowerBi , which redirect to azure login and breaks the application.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
   var @params = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"response_type", "code"},
            {"client_id", Properties.Settings.Default.ClientID},
            {"resource", "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"},
            {"redirect_uri", "http://localhost:13526/Redirect"}
        };


        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString.Add(@params);

        string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/";
        var authUri = String.Format("{0}?{1}", authorityUri, queryString);
        Response.Redirect(authUri);
}
```

After Authentication ,Azure issues the token and load the powerbi.

EmbedPowerBi

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EmbedPowerBi ()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    authResult = (AuthenticationResult)Session["authResult"];
    var token = authResult.AccessToken;
    ViewBag.Token = token;

    var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token, "Bearer");

    // Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
    using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
    {
        // Get a list of dashboards.
        var dashboards = await client.Dashboards.GetDashboardsInGroupAsync(GroupId);

        // Get the first report in the group.
        var dashboard = dashboards.Value.FirstOrDefault();
        //var dashboard = dashboards.Value.Where(w => w.Id == "DashboardId");


        // Generate Embed Token.
        var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
        var tokenResponse = await client.Dashboards.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, dashboard.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

        if (tokenResponse == null)
        {
            return View(new EmbedConfig()
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token."
            });
        }

        // Generate Embed Configuration.
        var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
        {
            EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
            EmbedUrl = dashboard.EmbedUrl,
            Id = dashboard.Id
        };

        return View(embedConfig);
    }

}
```

Problem I have faced beacuse of redirection other partial view gets affected the current application.

In the Home View i am loading partial view.

@Html.Partial("loadProduct");
@Html.Partial("_EmbedPowerBi");

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referring to the existing 'Developer Samples'?
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/App%20Owns%20Data/PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L133

It seems the redirection problem is causing a ViewModel binding to you `EmbedConfig`